# odoo 9 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am getting attribute error while evaluating the code, the code is working fine for odoo 8 but in odoo 9 it gives error.

Please suggest me the solution.

Here below is my code

---

```
def approve_loan(self ,cr ,uid ,ids ,context=None):
    move_pool = self.pool.get('account.move')
    period_pool = self.pool.get('account.period')
    timenow = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    loan_slip = self.browse(cr ,uid ,ids)[0]
    line_ids = []
    # get period 
    ctx = dict(context or {}, account_period_prefer_normal=True)
    search_periods = period_pool.find(cr, uid, loan_slip.start_date, context=ctx)
    period_id = search_periods[0]
```

Comment: So `period_pool` must be `None`, so `self.pool.get()` is returning `None`.

Comment: Can you provide the error Stack?

Answer (score 0):

**Why you get the error**

None is returned at the moment the model doesn't exist.

**Possible Reasons it returns none**

- You probably didn't the module needed for the model "account.period". (You should consider adding it to the dependencies of your module.)
- Odoo changed their modules so the model "account.period" doesn't exist anymore (You should figure out what it's replaced by and edit your code to use the new Odoo9 code)

Comment: I tried to figure it out for replaced model in place of 'account.period', since I am new to odoo I didn't get. Anyways, thanks for your kind help.